# how to output a component in angular that is provided via @Input()?

Tags: angular

I am implementing a popup modal component.
It receives a component via `@Input()` that should be displayed inside the popup component.

Current code is:

```
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  component: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

template:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <a class="popup__close">X</a>
    <div [outerHTML]="component"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when I provide a component like:
`<app-popup [component]="MyTestComponent"></app-popup>`

I get an output of the component definition like:
`class MyTestComponent implements OnInit ...`
But I want to see it's template.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass components through an `Input`. You should read about transclusion and use of the `ng-content` tag.

Your component template should look like this:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <a class="popup__close">X</a>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use your component like this:

```
<PopupComponent>
  <my-component></my-component>

  <!-- Or any content... -->
  <p>Anything</p>
</PopupComponent>
```

What is between the `PopupComponent` tags will be inserted where the `ng-content` tag is in your PopupComponent template.

If the content needs to be created dynamically you can also use Angular's [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Comment: and how then MatDialog is implemented?

Comment: the component that will be in the popup must be dynamic, I cannot write it in the template.

Comment: Then you can use dynamic component loading

Comment: Also MatDialog seems to be using injection, not Inputs https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: I have followed this guide: https://blog.ng-book.com/dynamic-components-with-content-projection-in-angular/

Comment: In the end it worked, but not on 100%. The component that was passed did not render it's logic. It rendered only static Template parts (the parts that should be output via *ngFor - are missing). It seems the logic in these components is not working.

Comment: If you know what component will go inside the popup, transcluding it with ng-content should work without any hassle as shown in my example. If you need to pass different component dynamically you can still use ngif or ngswitch to pass different components between the `<PopupComponent></PopupComponent>` tags

Comment: Yes, it is less dynamic but it will work for my project. I did it like you suggested. Thanks.